# How to get id value from html to php laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

1.How is it possible to get the value of id from inside h4 tag html. This id has a value of an integer as counter coming from my jquery

2. I need to pass the count to my php code to be like `$c = chr(64 + value of id image-gallery-count)` I'm having trouble with this for almost a week now. Hope anyone code help me here. See my code below.`$('#image-gallery-count').text($sel.data('count'));`

   ```
             <h4 id="image-gallery-count"></h4>

   <?php $html = '<h4 id="image-gallery-count"></h4>';
             $doc = new DOMDocument();
             $doc->validateOnParse = true;
             $doc->loadHTML($html);
             $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
             $belement = $doc->getElementById('image-gallery-count');
             echo $belement->nodeValue;
             $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
             $xpath->query("//*[@id='image-gallery-count']");

             $c = chr(64 + value of id here);// I want to add the value id of <h4 id="image-gallery-count"></h4>
             $b = chr(64 + 1);

   ?>
   ```

Comment: can you just append the needed value at runtime(in javascript)?

Comment: I am not sure what it is you need it to do please show example of what you are getting and what it is you want, maybe then we can give you an attak plan to get there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask